# Does A#.Net work in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compatibility, ada

As per the title. For those who don't know, it's basically Ada for .Net.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sharp_(.NET)), A#.Net has been folded into "GNAT for .Net" for future releases

> [AdaCore](http://www.adacore.com/home/) has taken over this development, and announced "GNAT for .NET", which is a fully supported .NET product with all of the features of A# and more.

Comment: It's been integrated into Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: That article was published a month before it was released. Damn not being able to edit comments.

Comment: Link to out-dated article removed, thanks. Editing comments will be a nice feature on SO, I usually delete and re-enter in place of editing.

Comment: Neat. I used to use Ada for all my pseudo-code, since real compilers used to cost too much. URL: http://www.adacore.com/home/gnatpro/add-on_technologies/dotnet/.

Answer (score 0):

The 2010 .Net. version is supposed to work with MVS 2008.